# Expected return

Tags: capm

I apologize if similar question has already been asked.

I have to calculate expected return on the stocks A & B via CAPM.

I know $w_A = 0.2$ & $w_B = 0.8$ (weights computed from given prices and quantities)

$β_A = 1.2$. I have calculated also $β_B = 0.95$ using above data.

Now, the task is to solve this equation:

$E(r_A,_B = r_F + β_A,_B(r_M - r_F)$

I think I can find $ρ$ (that I need for the covariance) from formula for $β_A$, and I get two solutions: $ρ_1 = 1.88$ & $ρ_2 = -1.13$

I don't know which is the right one, besides I can't find $r_F$ & $r_M$ so I'm stuck here.

Comment: "besides I can't find $r_F$ & $r_M$": $r_F$ is the risk-free rate, $r_M$ is the market/benchmark return.